# how to multiply and rename one image to n-times in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rename, batch-processing, copy-paste, video-processing

for making a video i want to multiply one image of a folder e.g. for 30fps and 30sec to 900 times with an uprising index.

How can i copy on image n-times and rename it with ffpeg?

How i did it by now:

mark all Strg C + Strg V
mark all Copy + Paste
2-4-8-16-32-64-128-256-576-1152

numbering i did with total commander "multi-rename-tool"

i like to do it with a loop-function in ffmpeg but i have no idea.
Has someone a suggestion and can help me please?
thx in advance!

Comment: Do you just want to make a video (presumably with audio) showing a still image for the duration of the music?

Comment: @kesh, thank you for your feedback. no sorry -  therefore i use the loop 1. The main idea is, i want to input image000 to blur with blurbox to output image001. then i want input image001 to output image002, and so on. 900 times. Unfortunatly it only works for the first picture: ffmpeg -y -i PAEC_%03d.png -vf boxblur=5 PAEC_%03d.png which lets image000 untouched and makes a blurred image001. But then image002 and the rest of the 900 images look like image001, not with a rising blur.

Comment: @LookAndSee don't answer comments in comments. Rather, [edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. Make sure you take the [tour] because this is not a threaded forum, and the Q&A is community curated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off to let a batch script to do the looping simply because your desired looping structure is not in the DNA of FFmpeg. If you must, the only way I can think of to do this in a single FFmpeg execution is to unwind the loop with a long filter chain. Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i PAEC_000.png \
    -filter_complex [0:v]boxblur=5,split[b1],\
                         boxblur=5,split[b2],\
                         ...
                         boxblur=5,split[b899] \
                         boxblur=5[b900] \
    -map [b1] PAEC_001.png \
    -map [b2] PAEC_002.png \
    ...
    -map [b900] PAEC_900.png
```